# How to open the same jQuery Dialog from dynamically and non-dynamically created controls

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to open the same jQuery dialog from different input text controls (including those that have been created dynamically)
This is what my page displays when it loads for the first time.[image]
When the user presses the "Add" button a new row is added to the table
[image]

So far so good. The problem comes when I have to open the dialog that will let users enter text into the inputs ( the dialog will display upon clicking on them) 
At first , I thought it would only be necessary to add a class to all the controls  and then using the class selector just call the dialog.
Unfortunately then I learned that with dynamic controls you have to use ".on" to attach them events.
Once overcome these difficulties , I run into one more that I haven't been able to solve yet. This is that if you don't want the dialog to be automatically open upon initialization, you have to set "autoOpen" to false. I did so but the only result I got was that none on the inputs worked.
I have also tried putting all the code ,regarding the dialog, into a function and then calling that function when an input is clicked 
I did also try declaring a variable and setting that variable to the dialog , something like this:

```
var dialog= $( "#dialog" )
```

But it didn't work either
I have tried some possibles solutions , but no luck as of yet.

**EDIT : Here's a fiddle so you can have a better idea of what I'm talking about:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3BXJp/

**Full screen result:** http://jsfiddle.net/3BXJp/embedded/result/

Here is the html code for the aspx page (Default.aspx):

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Expression Builder</legend>
            <table id="myTable" class="order-list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            IF(<input type="text" name="condition1" class="showDialog" />
                            :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="trueValue" class="showDialog" />
                            )
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="deleteRow"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                            <input type="button" id="addrow" value="+ Add" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="">
                            ELSE (
                            <input type="text" name="else" id="else" class="showDialog" />)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnEnviar" value="Send" />
    </div>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Add New Detail">
        <p>
            All the fields are required.</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="condition" id="lblcondition">
                        Condition</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="condition" id="condition" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="returnValue" id="lblreturnValue">
                        Return Value</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="returnValue" id="returnValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;
        $("button, input:submit, input:button").button();
        $('input:text').addClass("ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all");
        var NewDialog = $("#dialog-form");
        NewDialog.dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        var Ventana = $("#dialog-form");
        $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

            var counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

            $("#ibtnDel").on("click", function () {
                counter = -1
            });

            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            cols += '<td>ELSE IF(<input type="text" name="condition' + counter + '" class="showDialog1" /> </td>';
            cols += '<td>: <input type="text" name="TrueValue' + counter + '" class="showDialog1" />)</td>';

            cols += '<td><input type="button" id="ibtnDel"  value="-Remove"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            var txtCondi = newRow.find('input[name^="condition"]');
            var txtVarlorV = newRow.find('input[name^="TrueValue"]');
            newRow.find('input[class ="showDialog1"]').on("click", function () {

                //Seleccionar la fila
                $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("selectedRow");
                $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("selectedRow", this.clicked);

                Ventana.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 400,
                    title: "Builder",
                    buttons: {
                        "Add": function () {
                            txtCondi.val($("#condition").val());
                            txtVarlorV.val($("#returnValue").val());
                            $("#condition").val("");
                            $("#returnValue").val("");
                            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            //dialogFormValidator.resetForm();
                            $(this).dialog("destroy")
                        }

                    },

                    close: function () {
                        $("#condition").val("");
                        $("#returnValue").val("");
                        $(this).dialog("destroy")
                    }
                });
                return false;

            });

            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;
            $("button, input:submit, input:button").button();
            $('input:text').addClass("ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all");


        });


        $("table.order-list").on("click", "#ibtnDel", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
        $("#btnEnviar").click(function () {

            //Armo el objeto que servira de parametro, para ello utilizo una libreria JSON
            //Este parametro mapeara con el definido en el WebService
            var params = new Object();
            params.Expresiones = armaObjeto();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Mostrar",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    if (textStatus == "success") {
                        loadMenuVar(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
                }

            });

        });

        $(".showDialog").click(function () {

            Ventana.dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                title: "Constructor",
                buttons: [
                    { text: "Submit", click: function () { doSomething() } },
                    { text: "Cancel", click: function () { $(this).dialog("destroy") } }
                          ],

                close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("option", "autoOpen", false);
                    $(this).dialog("destroy")

                }
            });
            return false;
        });            

    });
```

This is the closest I've been able to get to the solution, but **still can't get the dialog to remain hidden until a input is clicked**

[image]

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Do you mean that the dialog appears (as a dialog box) when you first open the page? Or that you can see the dialog hanging around at the bottom of the HTML page? In the second case just style the HTML as `display:none` to hide it on the page and let the dialog show it. Also you should probably go back to having a single function deal with the dialog, there seems to be a lot of duplication your example.

Comment: It's the second case, the dialog appear at the bottom of the page whenever I close the dialog, because I had to set `autoOpen` to `true` so that the dialog can appear when an input is clicked. If don't include `autoOpen: true` the dialog will never be displayed since it is first loaded with an `autoOpen: false`

Comment: @SpaceDog I have created a jsfiddle. Do you think you could check it out?? http://jsfiddle.net/3BXJp/

Comment: my solution below works on the fiddle, I just put the style into the style box. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/rS5pF/. But read my comments below as well please ;).

Comment: @SpaceDog I've just seen your jsfiddle and the problem with bunch of divs being created seems to have disappeared:). I'll have a better look at it. Thank you SO MUCH!!!! (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because you're using `destroy()` rather than `close()` on the dialog. At the moment it looks like you're creating and destroying the dialog each time, don't do that. You should create the dialog once, isolate the dialog functionality to a separate function, and then just use `open()` and `close()` on it (you'll have to do some extra work to get the values into the right fields).

You can make your current code work if you style the dialog as hidden it'll stop happening, add this to your HTML (in the `<HEAD>`):

```
<style>
#dialog-form {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

you should probably have a separate style-sheet file you include that has that style in it. Similarly you should put all your JS in a separate file if it isn't already.

But I'd definitely look at re-writing the whole thing to follow the guidelines above, it does look like it can be made a lot simpler which makes it easier to support in the future.

**EDIT**

This is a simplified version that shows how I would do it.

*Script:*

```
var counter = 1; // Counter for number of rows
var currentRow = null; // Current row selected when dialog is active

// Create the dialog
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: "no-close", // Hide the 'x' to force the user to use the buttons
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    title: "Builder",
    buttons: {
        "OK": function(e) {
            var currentElem = $("#"+currentRow); // Get the current element
            currentElem.val($("#d_input").val()); // Copy dialog value to currentRow
            $("#d_input").val(""); // Clear old value
            $("#dialog-form").dialog('close');
        },
        "Cancel": function(e) {
            $("#d_input").val(""); // Clear old value
            $("#dialog-form").dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

// This function adds the dialog functionality to an element
function addDialog(elemId) {
    elem = $("#"+elemId);
    elem.on('click', function() {
        currentRow = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
    });

}

// Add functionality to the 'add' button
$("#addRow").on('click', function () {
    counter = counter + 1;
    var newId = "in"+counter;
    var newRow = "<tr><td><input id='"+newId+"' class='showDialog'></td></tr>";
    $('TBODY').append(newRow);
    // add the dialog to the new element
    addDialog(newId);
});

// add the dialog to the first row
addDialog("in1");
```

*HTML:*

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Expression Builder</legend>
        <table id="myTable" class="order-list">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><input id='in1' class='showDialog'></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
            <input type='button' id='addRow' value='add'></input>                
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnEnviar" value="Send" />
</div>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add New Detail">
  <input type="text" id="d_input" />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/FFvkY/)

This isolates the different functionality into different functions. You can easily expand it to do what you want. If you want the remove functionality I'd consider having a remove button for every row with a given class with a trigger function that removes that row (and the button). Then have a separate count of active rows. At the start use `disable()` to disable the single button, when you add a row `enable()` all the buttons of that class. When you remove a row then disable the buttons is existingRows <= 1.

Comment: It's because you're destorying the dialog -- which removes all trace and returns the HTML to the state is was beforehand (it's hidden first because jquery-ui does that when you did that). Basically destorying the dialog removes the autoOpen and everything else. Use `close()` instead.

Comment: I used destroy because `close` only hides the div , it doesn't remove it and as a result I end up with a bunch of divs in my source code(have you check it out) . Isn't that a problem???

Comment: I think that's because you're creating a new dialog each time. Use `open()` and `close()` instead.

Comment: You caught me when I was bored, I've added an example of how I would do it -- hopefully that gives you an idea how to adapt your version.

Comment: Thank you @SpaceDog!!!! I used your example and it worked just as I wanted it to. As for the remove functionality, I don't think I quite understand your idea. I do use a class to identify all the delete buttons and also when one of those buttons is clicked that whole row is deleted.But why should I have a separate count of active rows? Or enable and disable buttons?? Do you think you could possibly explain a little more about that??? I'm really curious :)

Comment: Thanks. If your solution works I wouldn't worry about the delete row stuff. When I've done similar I have a delete button that gets grayed out (via `disable`) when there's only one thing left to delete, so  I have to track when there's only one active row left -- but that's just how I do it -- if your version works then go with that. :)